# How to convert any .csv file to an excel file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I'm trying to convert any .csv file from this path to an excel file. The code works but I need to rename that .csv file manually. Is there a way to read and convert whatever .csv file without renaming it? Your input is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Processed_Report/Source1.csv')
read_file.to_excel (r'C:/Processed_Report/Source.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: @BigBen, yes that is why I'm looking for a syntax in Python to convert any .csv file in that path without renaming the fielaname manually to .xlsx file and rename it to Source.xlsx Thanks

Comment: @BigBen sorry the .ext is not suppose to be there. I edited my question. Thank you for correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't sure if i understood, but this is how you can read all file inside a folder and convert them to excel files.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Processed_Report/", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        base_name, ext = os.path.splitext(name)  #Split name, extension
        if ext in ".cvs":
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, name))
            df.to_excel(os.path.join(root, f'{base_name}.xlsx'))
```

Comment: @Christian, thank you for sharing the code. After converting the .csv file into an .xlsx file with your code, I wanted to rename that file to Source.xlsx. Where should I insert this code read_file.to_excel (r'C:/Processed_Report/Source.xlsx', index = None, header=True)

Comment: Because i'm getting this error message when I insert this on the next line NameError: name 'read_file' is not defined

Comment: Change base_name inside pd.to_excel(...) function like this: df.to_excel(os.path.join(root, 'Source.xlsx')).

Comment: Note if you use same output file name in case of multiple csv files in the folder the loop overwrites the output file every time

Comment: Follow up question Christian if I may, a column with numbers is automatically added in the Source.xlsx file. From the CSV file, it only has 2 columns (A, B) but in the converted Source.xlsx file, it added 1 column with row numbers without header plus A and B columns. Any advice please thanks

Comment: This is a index column to remove add index=False to save function df.to_excel(os.path.join(root, f'{base_name}.xlsx'), index=False)

Answer (score 0):

Using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


file_path = r"C:/Processed_Report"
files = [x for x in Path(file_path).glob("*csv")]
[pd.read_csv(x).to_excel(f"{file_path}/{x.stem}.xlsx", index=False) for x in files]
```